# Forward ISP IPv6 from LAN to secondary LAN

Tags: debian, routing, nat, ipv6, ip-forwarding

I want to **forward** (**or bridge, next to routing ipv4**) the IPv6 internet connection from the **LAN1** to **LAN2**.

IPv6 internet is accessible on **LAN1**.

I have a windows server, configured as NAT router between **LAN1** and **LAN2**. 
This server is the DHCP, and gateway for LAN2.
On the server, there is a Debian VM, and it's connected to **both LAN's**.

So if it's possible, i want to bridge ipv6, next to routing ipv4 on the linux vm, or on the windows server, or forward IPv6 connection, in any method to the LAN2.

So my question is, **what are the solutions** for this, and how to do them?
I am currently studying IPv4 VLSM subnetting, and i has a simple knowledge about IPv6, but i can't understand routing in the IPv6 yet.

**You can see the whole topology on the picture.**

Thanks in advance!

[Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSIN3.png)

Comment: "_i can't understand routing in the IPv6 yet._" IP routing works the same for both IPv4 and IPv6. Packets are routed between networks by the destination IP address in the packet header. The router looks in its routing table for a network that matches the destination address in the packet header, and forwards the packet to the next interface toward the destination if it finds a match, or it drops the packet if no match is found.

Comment: "_I have a windows server, configured as NAT router between LAN1 and LAN2._" You really do not want to NAT if you do not need to. You only NAT if you have overlapping addressing, or you need to send privately addressed packets to the public Internet. If your LAN1 and LAN2 are both privately addressed (not overlapping), then you should just route between them. If NAT is not necessary, it unnecessarily consumes resources and can break protocols and applications.

Answer (score 1):

Assign another, different /64 to LAN2, and route.

Obscuring your prefix is unhelpful as it removes details. Lots of global scope addresses with v6.  So I'll make up something.

Assume your provider delegates `2a01:0123:4567:8900::/56` to you.  The router for LAN1 might be `2a01:0123:4567:8901::1` and LAN2 `2a01:0123:4567:8902::1`. On a node in LAN2, default gateway is the 2 router. And just one more hop to the 1 router before the Internet.

---

Define why the VM needs to connect to both LANs. Maybe it has a routing or firewall function and needs interfaces in both. But a node that just needs to talk to stuff only needs to know the router on the local subnet.